# React List Components not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a list of Folders in React using the GET function in JQuery. This is my code:

```
function HorizontalNav() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="navbar navbar-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item me-3">
                            <a className=""><i className="bi bi-gear-fill"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a className="dropdown-toggle"><i className="bi bi-paint-bucket"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        );
}

function FolderList() {
    var m = [];
    $.get('get_folders', function(data) {
        for (let x of data.folders) {
            m.push(x);
        }
    });
    return <ul>{m.map((y) => { return <li>{y.name}</li>; })}</ul>;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="p-5">
            <HorizontalNav/>
            <div className="mt-3" id="folders">
                <FolderList/>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);
```

Every time I load the page, nothing happens. All I see is the HorizontalNav and not the list of Folders. FYI I'm using Flask on the backend, and the above code is JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) topic in the React documentation.

To get and save the data on initialization, I recommend the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks.
The `useEffect` hook corresponds to react's combined lifecycle methods `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`.
With `useState` the data can be saved in the local state. Appropriate getters and setters are provided for this purpose.

```
function HorizontalNav() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="navbar navbar-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item me-3">
                            <a className=""><i className="bi bi-gear-fill"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a className="dropdown-toggle"><i className="bi bi-paint-bucket"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function FolderList() {
    const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        $.get('/folders', function(data) { setFolders(data.folders) });
    }, []);

    return (
        <ul>{folders.map((x, i) => { return <li key={i}>{x.name}</li> })}</ul>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="p-5">
            <HorizontalNav/>
            <div className="mt-3" id="folders">
                <FolderList />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);
```